# Modify Poweroff dialog in AOSP (menu that when holding power key appears)

Tags: android, android-source

How I can modify the dialog which is shown when the user holds the power key?

I want the user to just be able to reboot his device and not to poweroff.

Where is related setting resides in AOSP?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://medium.com/@kpbird/in-depth-android-shutdown-sequence-f28e5b5b4076) is a nice article about shutdown in android.

According to above article we should take a look at this file :

> "frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/policy/GlobalActions.java"

Consider these lines in the file:

```
         String[] defaultActions = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(
                 com.android.internal.R.array.config_globalActionsList);
```

So we should modify `config_globalActionsList`. Here is the relevant `grep` results:

```
    $ grep -rnIi . -e 'config_globalActionsList' --exclude-dir=out/
    ./base/core/res/res/values/config.xml:2210:    <string-array translatable="false" name="config_globalActionsList">
    ./base/core/res/res/values-watch/config.xml:25:    <string-array translatable="false" name="config_globalActionsList">
    ./base/core/res/res/values/symbols.xml:1157:  <java-symbol type="array" name="config_globalActionsList" />
    ./base/services/core/java/com/android/server/policy/GlobalActions.java:271:                com.android.internal.R.array.config_globalActionsList);
```

The first entry is relevant. New array is like this (I have remove shutdown):

```
<string-array translatable="false" name="config_globalActionsList">
    <item>restart</item>
    <item>bugreport</item>
    <item>users</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [ShutdownThread](http://androidxref.com/7.1.2_r36/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/power/ShutdownThread.java#164) class, located at [frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/power/ShutdownThread.java](http://androidxref.com/7.1.2_r36/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/power/ShutdownThread.java#164)